# How to convert a column of data in a DataFrame filled with string representation of non-uniformed date formats to datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say:

```py
>>> print(df)

    location        date
    paris     23/02/2010
    chicago    3-23-2013
    ...
    new york  04-23-2013
    helsinki  13/10/2015
```

Currently, `df["date"]` is in `str`. I want to convert the date column to datetime using

```py
>>> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

I would get ValueError due to ParserError. This is because the format of the date is inconsistent (i.e. dd/mm/yyyy, then next one is m/dd/yyyy).

If I were to write the code below, it still wouldn't work due to the date not being uniformed and delimiters being different:

```py
>>> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

The last option that I could think of was to write the code below, which replaces all of the dates that are not formatted like the first date to `NaT`:

```py
>>> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce")
```

How do I convert the whole `date` column to datetime while having the dates not uniform in terms of the delimiters, and the orders of days, months and years?

Answer (score 1):

use, `apply` method of pandas

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date']),axis = 1)
```